# Cannot create an Android application in Intelli J

Tags: android, intellij-idea

[image]

I want to create a new Android Application but Intelli J does't show the Android option for creating a new application. I also have problems with other applications i previously created with Intelli J that worked fine until this morning. 
It shows a message Cannot find Android Facet. When I go to add a Facet it doesn't allow me.

Any idea?
I tried to uninstall intelli J various times but the same problem persists

Comment: IntelliJ is the company, IDEA is the IDE and AndroidStudio is a flavour of that IDE: https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html

Comment: how am I supposed to resolve my problem? I need to use Intelli J for developing my project

Comment: What version specifically are you using? The AndroidStudio one has all the tools you need packaged into it. You could take a default copy of IDEA and manually start adding components but that's a waste of time since it already exists. Follow the link I gave and go through the instructions. If you've done all that and it's still not working then we need much more info than "I can't make it work".

Comment: Can you create it using Android Studio? It has Gradle as well and can help you determine whether it's Gradle or IntelliJ IDEA issue.

Comment: Try to remove Idea settings foder. In linux it's hidden and located in user home directory and named ".IdeaIC13", I belive the same situation on Mac. In Winodws it should be someware in your user directory. Also try to add android sdk directory to PATH environmental varaible. Also try to add ANDROID_HOME environmental varaible.